# Hibernate validator internationalize when using XML

Tags: xml, internationalization, constraints, hibernate-validator

I'm using hibernate validator with xml like this:

```
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd"
                     xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">
    <default-package>org.hibernate.validator.quickstart</default-package>
    <bean class="com.totempool.persistence.data.User" ignore-annotations="true">
        <field name="firstName">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Min">
                <element name="value">2</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
        <field name="lastName">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
            <constraint annotation="com.totempool.persistence.constraint.IpValid"/>
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.Min">
                <element name="value">2</element>
            </constraint>
        </field>
        <field name="phones">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull"/>
        </field>
    </bean>
    <constraint-definition annotation="com.totempool.persistence.constraint.IpValid">
        <validated-by include-existing-validators="false">
            <value>com.totempool.persistence.constraint.IpValidImplementation</value>
        </validated-by>
    </constraint-definition>
</constraint-mappings>
```

My issue is that i need to internationalize the messages provided by default , i know that when using annotations it is possible to do this

```
message="{theMessage}"
```

and with an .properties file internationalize the message . i've tried this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261858/internationalization-in-hibernate-validators) but no luck. All other information that i've found is using annotations and non work with xml. So if someone can provide a tutorial,  some method that i can use to do this or tell me if this is even possible would be perfect.

EDIT

this is the exception that rises when i try to put a specific value to the constraint , i tried changing the message name but not work

```
  Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000113: message, groups, payload are reserved parameter names."}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to internationalize the default message of a (built-in) constraint, you don't need to modify the message parameter value. Just place `ValidationMessages.properties` (or any of the sub locales depending on which language you want to use) into the root of your class path and use the default keys, eg:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=My NotNull message
```

If you want to have specific messages per property (eg a specific message for the first name), you need indeed add something to your XML.

```
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd"
                     xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">
    <default-package>org.hibernate.validator.quickstart</default-package>
    <bean class="com.totempool.persistence.data.User" ignore-annotations="true">
        <field name="firstName">
            <constraint annotation="javax.validation.constraints.NotNull">
                <element name="message">{user.firstName.message}</element>
            </constraint>
...
</constraint-mappings>
```

In your properties file you then add:

```
user.firstName.message=The first name cannot be null
```

It is important not to forget the {} in the message parameter. They tell the validation engine that it deals with a message key and it needs to resolve the key against the validation messages bundle.

Comment: Hi , the first part : javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=My NotNull message did work but when i try to specify my own message it says message its a reserved word , see edits thanks

Comment: Found the solution  <message>{user.firstName.message}</message> , Thanks