# How to validate spring boot request body in different languages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I have an API written in spring boot, and I want it to accept request body in different languages. However, when parameters like age and phone number in request body are in some other language as shown below, the validation is failed on the API. So, how can I validate spring boot request body in different languages.

*The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261858/internationalization-in-hibernate-validators) is a different one because that question is regarding providing validation response message in different languages, but I need to validate the request body i.e. input parameters that are coming in different languages.*

**Request body in Chinese:**

```
{
    "name": "安德鲁",
    "age": "三十五",
    "phone" "十二亿三千四百五十六万七千八百九十"
}
```

**POJO in spring boot:**

```
public class Employee {

    private String id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Max(65)
    @NotNull
    private Integer age;

    @Pattern(regexp="(^$|[0-9]{10})")
    @NotNull
    private String phone;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Internationalization in Hibernate validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261858/internationalization-in-hibernate-validators)

Comment: @hous, No, because that question is regarding providing validation response message in different languages, but I need to validate the request body i.e. input parameters that are coming in different languages.